# different level of user role in a django application

Tags: python, django

I am about to implement a new django software.

The software is basically about to build a community platform. 
The community has a moderator, each user when they sign up, they have to request access to community. Now it is the community moderator who will approve.

Now as in stackoverflow, based on good karma, user can gain privilege to edit or delete content from site.

Basically it is about granting permission level to users.

So the question is -

1. is it good to open admin interface to different users?
   I guess it is not. Because you do not want everyone to peep into the schema.

So the question then boils down to, what is an optimized way of implementing the role based in a django application.

Please let me know your thoughts, thanks.

Comment: I have the similar problem. The django default permission system doesn't help much on this. I am thinking either we write some custom permission on it or we assign different roles to user and user role limit the access to different content rather than actual permissions. I'd like to know what is the good solution to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's not a good idea to open the admin interface to users. You'll probably want to consult the [Django documentation on authorization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization), which features some helpful hints about how to do it. I'd recommend making custom group permissions and progressing users through the groups based on their karma level and/or restricting certain actions to be hidden to users below a certain karma level.

You may also want to review the [section on creating a custom User object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/) as I think you'll find that useful when extending the user object to include a karma field.